# redis-server installation error on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, ubuntu, celery

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFEbs.png)

I'm trying to install redis-server for celery use, but I'm getting an error.
how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here: [cannot install redis-server on ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668845/cannot-install-redis-server-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Trying installing with IPv6 disabled.